# The elements of collections of a deserialized JSON object are LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am sending a request to the controller https://pastebin.com/d4SHZuZh. JSON deserialize using Builder from this class. `@JsonDeserialize(builder = ContributionNewRequest.Builder.class)`

The elements of the collection are `? extends MovieInfoDTO` objects inheriting from `MovieInfoDTO`.

when getting items from e.g. list `elementsToAdd`

```
contribution.getElementsToAdd()
            .forEach(boxOffice -> {
                ...
            });
```

it turns out that the `boxOffice` element is a `java.util.LinkedHashMap` object.

I found a mention on the internet on the Internet http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-collection-array that JSON default sets the elements of the collection as `LinkedHashMap`.

What do I need to do to make the objects of the correct type?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.jonki.popcorn.common.dto.movie.BoxOffice
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
```

Answer (score 3):

You should custom your deserialize builder.

Try something like this

```
public class CustomDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<List<? extends MovieInfoDTO>> {
    protected CustomDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public List<? extends MovieInfoDTO> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = jsonParser.getText();
        TypeReference type = new TypeReference<List<? extends MovieInfoDTO>>() {};
        return objectMapper.readValue(json, type);
    }
}
```

Finally add `@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)` before your `elementsToAdd` property

Hope this will help you a bit.

Comment: I need to create a three classes for deserializing for a list, map and set?

Comment: And how do I want to submit the ```Set <String> tags```, I need to create another class for deserialization? In general, I will have to create a lot of such classes for a project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert it using following code.

```
public <T> List<T> jsonToObjectList(String json, Class<T> tClass) throws IOException {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            List<T> ts = objectMapper.readValue(json, objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, tClass));
            return ts;
        }
```

Comment: I need a more automatic method so that I do not have to manually pass the object through this method every time. Good annotations would be good.